# Is there a way to show the Bluetooth Transaction as well in the Android Studio

Tags: android, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy, android-studio-2.2

Is there a way to see the transaction happening on the Bluetooth I/f in the Android Monitor ?  Just like below Network Transaction is shown.

[image]

Comment: No, it is not possible